# ExecuteSQL Concatenate string and integer

Tags: filemaker

I am using trying to populate a dropdown using magicVaueList hack and ExecuteSQl and I am having trouble with joining a text and number.

Here is my code:

```
MVL_Dropdown ( ExecuteSQL ( "select L.Product  +  GetAsText( L.Quantity )
                             from T08_ESTIMATES E 
                             join T09_EST_LINE_ITEMS L on E.ID_Estimate = L.id_estimate 
                             where E.ID_Estimate = ? "; ""; ""; T19_TASKS::preitem ) )
```

The trouble I get is with the `+  GetAsText( L.Quantity )` where I have also tried `&  GetAsText( L.Quantity )` will no results but if I was to remov ethe join like:

```
MVL_Dropdown ( ExecuteSQL ( "select L.Product
                             from T08_ESTIMATES E 
                             join T09_EST_LINE_ITEMS L on E.ID_Estimate = L.id_estimate 
                             where E.ID_Estimate = ? "; ""; ""; T19_TASKS::preitem ) )
```

Then it works minus the fact that I will need both values. I'm therefore certain the problem exists Concatenating my text and number but I'm quite new to FileMaker and not sure what to use to get it to work.
.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering i had to use a double pipe like so:

```
L.Product || ' - ' || L.Quantity

MVL_Dropdown ( ExecuteSQL ( "SELECT L.Product || ' - ' || L.Quantity || ' off'
                             FROM T08_ESTIMATES E 
                             JOIN T09_EST_LINE_ITEMS L ON E.ID_Estimate = L.id_estimate 
                             WHERE E.ID_Estimate = ? "; ""; ""; T19_TASKS::preitem ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

**STRVAL** - Converts a value of any type to a character string

Here I wanted to concatenate an integer "Quantity" and string "Units":

```
ExecuteSQL ( "
    SELECT p.Description, STRVAL ( m.Quantity ) || p.Units
    FROM JobMaterials m
    JOIN Products p
    ON m.kf_Product = p.kp_ProductID
    WHERE m.kf_JobID = ?
" ;
    "¦" ; "¶" ;
    Jobs::kp_JobID
)
```